# How to Access Settings file from .py file - DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is my project structure. I am trying to access settings.py file from lookups.py[image]

I am importing using following code,

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.append('/path/to/django/project')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'manageemployee.settings')
django.setup()
from manageemployee.apps.employee.hrmmongodb import DBMixin
from manageemployee.settings import EVENT_STORE_DICT
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manageemployee'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use settings by importing the object `django.conf.settings` wherever it was needed instead of the settings file itself as you are trying,

Example:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Do Something
```

So in your use case:

```
from django.conf import settings

EVENT_STORE_DICT = settings.EVENT_STORE_DICT 
# Do Something
```

Note that `django.conf.settings` isn’t a module – it’s an object. So
importing individual settings is not possible:

```
from django.conf.settings import DEBUG  # This won't work.
```

> You can also find the detailed information in the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)